# UIWebView instead of Teapot in Vuforia App

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm developing an Augmented Reality iOS App with Vuforia. I need to change the Teapot (I'm working over the ImageTargets sample) with a UIWebView that will provide some links and some static text.

Is there a way to render a UIWebView as a texture with OpenGL-ES and draw it instead of the Teapot?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can do that. I talk from a purely `Vuforia Unity` standpoint, but a similar construction can be used and the logic stays the same.

Construct a cube and add the texture with the Text over it. But for this you'll have to create the texture to add using `OpenGL`

With this cube replace it with the teapot on top of your `ImageTarget`

Now if your words need to be clicked, you can always use `Virtual Buttons`. I've explained about same in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522795/load-ar-model-through-button-tap-in-android)